# notepad++ replace a string in next (3 or 4 ) lines

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a text file of 183419 lines, where I would like to replace the entire line of:

```
3 _TYPE PHOTO
```

with:

```
3 _TYPE DOCUMENT
```

but only if it is 3 or 4 lines after a line that begins with:

```
3 FILE d:\genie\grogan\doc\......
```

For example:

```
3 FILE d:\genie\grogan\doc\mills\Mills Albert 1884 Birth Partial Transcript.jpg  
3 TITL Mills Albert 1884 Birth Partial Transcript  
3 _SCBK Y  
3 _TYPE PHOTO
```

or:

```
3 FILE d:\genie\grogan\doc\mills\Mills Albert 1884 DeathTranscript.jpg  
3 TITL Mills Albert 1884 DeathTranscript  
3 _SCBK Y  
3 _PRIM Y  
3 _TYPE PHOTO
```

but not for this situation:

```
3 FILE d:\genie\grogan\photos\grogan edward\Grogan Thelma Simpson Jim.jpg  
3 _SCBK Y  
3 _TYPE PHOTO
```

This is a task that would be required to be run monthly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a regular expression search and replace, ensure **Dot matches newline** is not selected. Setting **Find what** to `^(3 FILE d:\\genie\\grogan\\doc\\(.*\r\n){3,4})3 _TYPE PHOTO$` and **Replace with** to `\13 _TYPE DOCUMENT`.

The `(.*\r\n){3,4}` part matches the end of the `genie\\grogan\\doc` line plus 2 or 3 more complete lines. The `(3 FILE ... )3 _TYPE PHOTO$` part matches the two specified strings and the enclosing brackets capture all the text except for the line to be replaced. The `\1` in the replacement string inserts the captured text, the rest of the string is the new text wanted.

Tested with Notepad++ 6.3.2 on your test lines.

Depending on your line endings, you may need to adjust the `\r\n` part of the **Find what** string. The examples do not cover all the options, so you may also need to change the `{3,4}` part to `{4,5}` depending on the exact meaning of "*only if it is 3 or 4 lines after*"

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and clear explanation, but I could not get a match.  [link]http://www.groganmob.com/extpgs/img/notepad01.jpg  and [link]http://www.groganmob.com/extpgs/img/notepad02.jpg.  I tried "FILE :\\D:\\.." in case case sensitive, as well as {3,4} to {4,5} and {3,6}. Also tried \r\n and \r.

Comment: ah! I forgot to have Regular expression turned on. Fantastic, many thanks :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: If the question has been answered then please *accept* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bookmark your lines
2. Do a regular expression to bookmarked lines only (just like **AdrianHHH** said)